# "She approved my having been called" is this grammatically correct?

Tags: gerunds

She approved **my having been** called

my or me?

is it the gerund or the participle?

Answer (score 0):

She did not approve you, she approved the act of you being called.  So, the "my" version is correct.  However, colloquially, you will hear the "me" version.